# Non-uniform distribution over a binary set

Tags: probability, binary

Let’s consider a non-uniform distribution over ${0,1}^n$ where $0$ comes with probability $0.4$ and $1$ with probability $0.6$. If $n=5$, which is the probability of the string (for example) $11001$?

Comment: If I understand the definition correctly, any particular ordered string will have probability $0.4^n 0.6^m$ where $n$ is the number of $0$s and $m$ is the number of $1$s in the string.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $$0.6^3 \times 0.4^2 = 0.03456.$$ That's because (assuming that each char value is independent from the others) the probability factorizes, e.g.

$$P(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1,X_3 = 0,X_4 = 0,X_5 = 1)  = P(X_1 = 1)P(X_2 = 1)P(X_3 = 0)P(X_4 = 0)P(X_5 = 1).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And it is the same probability of any other strings with three 1s and two 0s which differ from 11001 only from the order? To be more general, any string in this example with the same number of zeroes and ones has the same probability?